# IMAP GMAIL doesnt allow

Tags: gmail, imap

It was possible before to import mails with IMAP, now only POP, I was try to go on Forwarding and POP/IMAP and there ENABLE IMAP, but still nothing.

Is there any other option for IMAP, or not?

Comment: please edit your question is include [example] describe your issue including error messages.   imap can definitely be used with Gmail another option would be the Gmail api

Comment: Is there a programming question in here?